# net::ERR_FAILED while loading local .json file?

Tags: javascript, svg, lottie, bodymovin

I am using bodyworks and lottie to load a custom SVG animation, and for some reason it is throwing a GET error. The path to the file is correct as it loads it fine when i copy and paste it into the browser so I am unsure what is going wrong?

```html
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById("animationContainer"), // the dom element that will contain the animation
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    path: 'data.json' // the path to the animation json
});
```

The file was originally in a nested folder but i thought that may be a cause of some of the errors so I moved it, however it is still unable to load it. Any help would be appreciated

```
> bodymovin.js:1300 GET file:///G:/My%20Drive/YetiTech/YetiTechNewSite/YetiTech/The%20Fresh%20Site%20of%20Bel%20Air/data.jsonnet::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Your browser is blocking access to local files because security. The right thing to do is to spin up a small dev http-server (often integrated in popular code-editors, or available as plugin).  You can't do web dev without it really.

Answer (score 0):

try to download and install mamp web server to create your local web server https://www.mamp.info/, then move the folder animation inside of the localhost folder and open it directly on the browser, for example localhost/animation-example/